# Firebase messaging service in unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-service

I am developing an `Android` app in Unity and I want to add `firebaseCloudMessaging` for push `notifications`.

I created native android plugin by extending `FirebaseMessagingService`.
With `AndroidJNI` I can access static members of created class but `onMessageReceived` and onNewToken are never called.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
- First problem was that I have been using .jar and not .aar (generated from android studio), .aar also contains AndroidManifest.xml (.jar doesn't) so Unity can merge all Manifests in to the one. Without manifest its service is not listed in final AndroidManifest.
- Second problem was that I put my .jar in custom folder under /Assets/Plugins/Android/my_folder/my_plugin.jar, and it should be under /Assets/Plugins/Android/my_plugin.jar (only with .aar extension).

After all that my service enters onCreate method (inherited from Service class) but immediately after that onDestroy is called (also inherited from Service class).